# When I deactive WooCommerce Plugin, I want to take a action in My plugin

Tags: plugin-development, deactivation

I have a WordPress plugin which is dependent on WooCommerce. When a user uninstalls or deactivates the WooCommerce plugin, in this time, I mean when WooCommerce plugin register_deactivation_hook, I want to take a notice in my active current plugin. How can I do this? please help.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to do this, you can either check for the main plugin file or you can check for the WooCommerce class.  When I make a plugin dependent on some other plugin I usually check for the plugin file, but for WooCommerce I check for the WooCommerce class.

```
<?php    
    function yourplugin_init() {
        if( !function_exists( 'is_plugin_inactive' ) ) :
            require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
        endif;
        //COMMON WOOCOMMERCE METHOD
        if( !class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) :
        //ALTERNATIVE METHOD
        //if( is_plugin_inactive( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) :
            add_action( 'admin_init', 'yourplugin_deactivate' );
            add_action( 'admin_notices', 'yourplugin_admin_notice' );
            function yourplugin_deactivate() {
                deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
            }
            function yourplugin_admin_notice() {
                echo '<div class="error"><p><strong>WooCommerce</strong> must be installed and activated to use this YOURPLUGIN.</p></div>';
                if( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );
            }
        endif;
    }
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yourplugin_init' );
?>
```

First, put the above code in your primary plugin file before any of the custom functionality you're adding.

We create a function that we run on `plugins_loaded`; it checks if the WP `is_plugin_inactive` function executes, if not, it loads the WP plugin file.

Next we check if a) the `WooCommerce` class does NOT exist or b) the alternative method which I've commented out, we check if the WooCommerce plugin is INACTIVE using the plugin's main PHP file (ie. `woocommerce/woocommerce.php`).

Now, IF we've established that WooCommerce isn't active (using one of the two methods above) we hook into two separate actions.
`admin_init`
`admin_notices`

Then we have two functions `yourplugin_deactivate()` and `yourplugin_admin_notice()` which are pretty self explanatory.   We deactivate the your plugin and then we post a notice at the top of the admin screen telling the user what we've done and why.

And there you go...